# Using wix to install a windows service that may already be installed

Tags: wix, windows-services, windows-installer

I'm using WiX 3.1.1 to install an exe and a service. Sometimes, the MSI install fails with a fairly generic error:

```
Error 1923. Service 'MyService' (MyService) could not be installed.
Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.
```

Experimentally, this appears to be because the service already exists, and my xml uses `Vital="yes"`

I would like to have the MSI ensure the service is installed, but accept (or repair) it if it's already present. It sounds like I should set `Vital="no"`, will this cause it to ignore *other* errors? Is there a way to limit what kind of errors are ignored? Is there a best practice I'm missing?

For reference, a redacted snippet of my xml:

```xml
<Component Id="REDACTED" Guid="{REDACTED}" Win64="yes">
  <File
      Id="filB754EE270009E240193A8279D1529A43"
      Name="myservice.exe"
      KeyPath="yes"
      DiskId="1"
      Source="SourceDir\File\filB754EE270009E240193A8279D1529A43" />
  <ServiceControl
      Id="MyService"
      Name="MyService"
      Start="install"
      Stop="both"
      Remove="uninstall"
      Wait="no" />
  <ServiceInstall
      Id="MyService"
      Name="MyService"
      Type="ownProcess"
      Start="auto"
      ErrorControl="normal"
      Vital="yes"
      Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]"
      Arguments="svc -config &quot;C:\Program Files\MyService\conf\service.flags&quot;"
      Description="My Service">
    <ServiceConfig
        ServiceName="MyService"
        FirstFailureActionType="restart"
        SecondFailureActionType="restart"
        ThirdFailureActionType="restart"
        ResetPeriodInDays="1"
        RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="5"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" />
  </ServiceInstall>
</Component>
```

Comment: Who/what could have already installed this service? Is it another installer you control?

Comment: Almost certainly an earlier version of the MSI, or even the same MSI. 

I think what's happening is that an end user does an uninstall, but for some reason the service is lingering. For example, if the Service Control Manager is open, a service won't be properly uninstalled. And subsequent installs fail with the aforementioned error.

Comment: Could you not just add a ServiceControl entry to stop and/or delete the service during installation?  Or a Custom Action to kill associated processes during installation/repair (NOT REMOVE~=ALL) etc?

Comment: I think the ServiceControl  is set that way? From what I can tell, the underlying problem is that the service _cannot_ be removed if the Service Control Manager is open. It can only be "scheduled for deletion". 

But that state makes the ServiceInstall step fail.

Comment: So far, my best approach is to do a lot of rebooting